# Changing title of the page - determining whats the current page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on codeigniter and I wonder whats the best way to change title dynamically. Eg. title will change depending if you are on home page, single post page, category pages, etc.

The only solution i can think of is to make separate function and compare current URL ( from address bar ) with structure of the single post page, category page, home page

Something like this:

```
public function current_title() { 
   if($this->uri->segment(2) == 'post') { 
      // will return post title 
    }

   if($this->uri->segment(2) == 'category') { 
      // will return archive title 
    }

    if(current_url() == base_url()) { 
      // this is home page 
    }
```

If anyone worked with this before, any advice highly appreciated

Comment: just pass title from the controller to the view

Comment: @Charles0429 EXACTLY! thanks :) lol so simple i don't know how I couldn't think of that. Complicating without reason :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use the uri for this, but instead the controller and action name and the language class :

```
public function current_title() 
{
    $this->lang->load('titles.php', 'en');

    return $this->lang->line(
        $this->router->fetch_class().'.'.$this->router->fetch_method()
    );
}
```

You will have a key like `MyClass.myMethod` for your translation. Just add your titles in your `titles.php` file :

```
$lang['MyClass.myMethod'] = "The title";
$lang['MyOtherClass.myOtherMethod'] = "The other title";
```

Read more about translation : 
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/language.html 
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/language_helper.html

Comment: I use the same way, it's clean and logic.

Answer (score 1):

//in the controller you should do like this:

```
 class Home extends your_Controller {
      public function __construct() {
          parent:: __construct();
         }
       function index()
       { 
       $this->data['pageTitle'] = 'Your page title';
        $data['main_content'] = 'home';
        $this->load->view('includefolder/viewname', $data);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
$PHPFile = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'.php');
switch ($PHPFile) {
    case 'index': $PageTitle = 'Home'; break;
    case 'products': $PageTitle = 'Products'; break;
    case 'services': $PageTitle = 'Services'; break;
}
```

You can use string searches or whatever is needed. I use this method since I have the header of the page as a function in library.

Answer (score 0):

As we have a controller function for each view so you can easily get function name from url

```
$this -> router -> fetch_module();
```

so you can work with it.